# Search for key and value in php arrays

Tags: php, arrays

So I have two array, the first one is like:

```
$MyArray    = [
    ['id' => 1, number => 32],
    ['id' => 2, number => 4]
];
```

and the other is like:

```
$OtherArray = [
    ['id' => 1, 'show' => X],
    ['id' => 5, 'show' => X]
];
```

Where is X, I want it to be equal with the 'number' value of $MyArray where key 'id' = its id.

If there is no `$MyArray.id` which is equal to `$OtherArray.id` then it should return 0.

I hope you understand what I mean. I tried everything, what I could, yet, with no success.

Comment: Have you tried something ? (Also your array structure is a bit unclear how many dimension your array has!)

Comment: That's not valid syntax for an array

Comment: Read about array_keys, in_array and array_search to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) loop here?

Here is a quick example... [PHPaste Snippet](https://phpaste.ga/paste/e44f50)

```
<?php

$firstArray = array(
    array(
        "id" => 1,
        "something" => "Hello, World!"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 3, // 3 on purpose
        "something" => "Hello, mom?"
    )
);

$secondArray = array(
    array(
        "id" => 1,
        "thing" => null
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 2,
        "thing" => null
    )
);

foreach ($firstArray as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($secondArray as $k => $v) {
        if ($value['id'] == $v['id']) {
            echo "Found one!\n------\n" . print_r($value, true) . "\ncontains the same ID as\n\n" . print_r($v, true) . "\n------\n";
            // you may also do this if you want
            // $secondArray[$k]['thing'] = $value['id'];
            // this would set "thing" (in the second array) to the value of "id" (in the first array)
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Here is a second example, displaying how you could use it as a function... [PHPaste Snippet](https://phpaste.ga/paste/a48999).

Note: I used the **OLD** array syntax because it's easier for new programmers to understand.

So, essentially what you are doing is iterating through each item in `$firstArray`, comparing it to each item in `$secondArray`, by doing a nested `foreach` within side the first `foreach` if that makes sense...?

Here is what I just said in simple form:

```
go through each item in array 1
--> compare it to each item in array 2
```

You may also notice my use of PHP's lovely function, [`print_r()`](http://php.net/print_r). This displays objects and arrays in a slightly, clearer, form.

You can also see that I am getting the values from within the arrays by using `$value['id']` and `$v['id']`. These were defined in my foreach declaration, `foreach ($firstArray as $key => $value)`; `$value` is an [associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), so you can simply get a value by key just as you would if you created an array like this:

```
$myArray = [
    "id" => 1
];
```

and grabbed values like this:

```
echo $myArray['id']; // 1
```

Hopefully this helped.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Bryan could you read over my answer again and let me know if it's OK now?

Comment: Yes, this is much better. Now the answer has enough context to stand on its own if the links ever go dead.

Comment: @Bryan I aim to please. ;)